# No compile errors, issues with structs and 2D arrays, and I never reach my second print statement?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm new to C and trying to wrap my head around pointers, structs, and 2D arrays. Whenever I learn a new language, I try to write a small game in it.

I have a struct -- named `Map` -- which contains a pointer to a pointer to create a 2D array, and a function called `createMap()`, which should fill in the arrays with either 0's or 1's.

In my `main()` function, I have a few debug printf statements. The first one is fired, but the second one is not. I'm using the gcc compiler, and am not receiving any error messages.

What am I doing wrong?

The `Map` struct and the `createMap()` function:

```
typedef struct {
    int x, y;
    int **map;
} Map;

Map createMap(int size, int x, int y) {
    Map m;
    m.x = x;
    m.y = y;
    m.map = malloc(x * sizeof(int *));

    for (int i=0; i<y; i++) {
        m.map[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(int));
    }

    for (int i=0; i<x*y; i++) {
        m.map[i][i] = randomInteger(i, 0, 1, 1);
    }

    return m;
}
```

The `main()` function:

```
    int main() {
    printf("Determining map size...");
    int size, x, y;
    x = 10;
    y = 5;

    if (x > y) {
        size = x;
    } else {
        size = y;
    }

    Map map = createMap(size, x, y);

    printf("Printing map...");
    printMap(map);

    for (int i=0; i<size;i++) {
        free(map.map[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) is by default *line buffered*. That means the buffer is flushed (actually written to the terminal) only when the buffer is full *or a newline is printed*.

Comment: By the way, you have a memory leak in your program.

Comment: You're only filling the *diagonal*. Everything else is garbage. To fill a 2-d array you need to have a *nested loop*

Comment: Debbugging with `printf()` is problematic, because `stdout` is line-buffered by default (fully buffered if it is not an interactive device). I recommend replacing debug-printfs with `fprintf(stderr, ...)`.

Comment: The  problem is `map[i][i]` when `i` is iterating from 0 to `x*y-1`. In other words, `map[49][49]` is way outside the bounds of the array that you've allocated.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was just reading other answers that you've written haha. Can I ask where the memory leak is? I'm from the Python/JS world, so playing clean up with memory has been a pain for me.    

@EOF Thanks for the advice on `stdout` and `fprintf`. I've replaced the statements with fprintf.       

@AnttiHaapala You're correct, it is still a bit early where I live and I missed that. Thank you.    

@user3386109 I see; I was expected some sort of warning or error. Thank you.

Comment: You free every element of `map` (i.e. `map.map[i]`) but you don't free the map (i.e. `map.map`) itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is wrong and invokes undefined behavior:

```
for (int i=0; i<x*y; i++) {
    m.map[i][i] = randomInteger(i, 0, 1, 1);
}
```

It should be:

```
for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<y; j++) {
        m.map[i][j] = randomInteger(i*x+j, 0, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

If you're using two dimensional arrays expect nested loops.

Also, you have a typo here:

```
for (int i=0; i<y; i++) {
    m.map[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(int));
}
```

Should be

```
for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
    m.map[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(int));
}
```

That's `i<x` not `i<y` to agree with your allocation statement above.

In `main` you have some erroneous code here:

```
for (int i=0; i<size;i++) {
    free(map.map[i]);
}
```

Should be

```
for (int i=0; i<x;i++) {
    free(map.map[i]);
}
free(map.map);
```

to agree with your allocations.

Comment: @Yonlif: Because it's a double-indirect pointer not a true multi-dimensional array the compiler has to retain a shadow of both loops. If it were a true multi-dimensional array (which is a simpler memory layout and makes the inner dimension size known at compile time) it actually can reduce it to a single loop.